# How can I retrieve the attributes for images using the populate attribute in Flamelink?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, flamelink-cms

I'm trying to use the `populate` attribute in the Flamelink `get()` query to populate images, as I've noticed that setting `populate: true` slows down the response time for the request.

I'm trying this:

```
const content = await flamelinkApp.content.get({
    schemaKey: page,
    populate: [{
     field: "images",
     sizes: {
       width: 1920,
       height: 999,
       quality: 1,
     },
    }],
});
```

However, all images only return their ID. Ideally, I just want their `url` returned - so, the `sizes` attribute might not be what I'm after, but I'd just like *something* back when using populate for now.

For reference, here is where I first read about using the populate attribute to speed up queries: https://github.com/flamelink/flamelink-js-sdk/issues/104#issuecomment-536525185

And here is information on the `get()` query itself: https://flamelink.github.io/flamelink/#/content?id=get